# SPARK SQL query for match output

Tags: apache-spark-sql, match

I have 2 ds as below

ds1:

```
CustId  Name    Street1      City                      
=================================                    
1       Ron     1 Mn strt    Hyd                                
2       Ashok   westend av   Delhi                        
3       Rajesh  5th Cross    Mumbai                    
4       Venki   2nd Main     NY
```

ds2:

```
Id       CustName    CustAddr1       City
=========================================
11       Ron         1 Mn Street     Hyd                        
12       Ron         eastend avn     Patna                           
13       Rajesh      2nd Main        Mumbai                             
14       Girish      100ft rd        BLR                                
15       Dinesh      60ft            Mum                                  
16       Rajesh      1st Cross       Mumbai
```

I am trying to find an exact match like `ds1.Name --> ds2.CustName`, `ds1.city --> ds2.city`

Output:

```
GrpID     Rec_Id   Count ds1.cond         Rec_Id    Count   ds2.cond
======================================================================
1         1        1     Ron + Hyd        1001      1       Ron + Hyd
2         2        1     Rajesh + Mumbai  1002      2       Rajesh + Mumbai
```

How to write (SPARK) SQL query for it?
I tried

```
final Dataset<Row> rslt = spark.sql("select * from ds1 JOIN ds2 ON ds1.Name==ds2.CustName");
```

(using only name)
but it gives output of mXn for m matching rows in ds1 with n matching rows in ds2.
My first work on this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Needs a little clarity from what I can observe.

Comment: Can you please tell me about your point of thinking or clarity you are looking for?